# SSL_CONNECT fails with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Having strange connection failure with openssl SSLConnect with my SSLCLIENT.

We are trying to establish ssl connection with a server. We notice that SSL_CONNECT is failing with error code "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL".

For further depth we tried printing strerror(errno) which return "scuccess" "0".

However i am just trying to understand what might be the exact cause for this issue

Added code snippet for SSL init and connect::

request some guidance:

```
int setupSSL(int server){ 

        int retVal = 0; 
        int errorStatus = 0; 
        int retryMaxCount = 6; 
        static int sslInitContext=0; 

    if(sslInitContext == 0) 
    { 
                if(InitCTX() != 0) 
                { 
                        return -1; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                        sslInitContext=1; 
                } 
    } 

    retVal = SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */ 
        if ( retVal != 1 ) 
        {   
                /* perform the connection */ 
                sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SOCKET:Could not set ssl FD: %d %s\n",retVal,strerror(retVal)); 
                debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 
                CloseSocket(server); 
                return -1; 
        } 
        do 
        { 
                retVal = SSL_connect(ssl); 
                errorStatus = SSL_get_error (ssl, retVal); 
                switch (errorStatus) 
                { 
                        case SSL_ERROR_NONE: 
                                retVal = 0;                         
                                break; 
                        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ: 
                        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE: 
                                retVal = 1; 
                                break; 
                        default: 
                                sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Could not build SSL session(Other error): %d %s\n",errorStatus,strerror(errno)); 
                                debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 
                                CloseSocket(server); 
                                return -1;                             
                } 
                sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:SSL CONNECTION Under PROGRESS: %d with remaining retries %d\n",errorStatus,retryMaxCount); 
                debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 

                if (retVal) 
                { 
                        struct timeval tv;         
                        fd_set sockReadSet; 
                        tv.tv_sec = 2; 
                        tv.tv_usec = 0;          
                        FD_ZERO(&sockReadSet); 
                        FD_CLR(server, &sockReadSet); 
                        FD_SET(server,&sockReadSet); 

                        retVal = select(server+1, &sockReadSet, NULL, NULL, &tv); 
                        if (retVal >= 1) 
                        { 
                                  retVal = 1; 
                        } 
                         else 
                        { 
                                  retVal = -1; 
                        } 
                        retryMaxCount--; 
                        if (retryMaxCount <= 0 ) 
                                break;         
                } 
        }while(!SSL_is_init_finished (ssl) && retVal == 1); 
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); 
    if(cert == NULL) 
        { 
            debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Unable to retrive server certificate\n",TRACE_LOG); 
                CloseSocket(server); 
                return -1; 
    } 
    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl)!=X509_V_OK) 
        { 
            debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Certificate doesn't verify\n",TRACE_LOG); 
                CloseSocket(server); 
            return -1; 
    } 
    /*X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID (X509_get_subject_name (cert),  NID_commonName,  peer_CN, 256); 
    if(strcasecmp(peer_CN, cnName)){ 
         debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Common name doesn't match host name\n",TRACE_LOG); 
         return -1; 
     }*/ 
           return 0; 
   // LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile); 
} 


int InitCTX(void) 
{ 
        int errorStatus = 0; 
        static int isSslInit = 1; 
        if(isSslInit) 
        { 
                OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();/* Load cryptos, et.al. */ 
                SSL_load_error_strings();/* Bring in and register error messages */ 
                if(SSL_library_init() < 0) 
                { 
                        debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Could not initialize the OpenSSL library\n",TRACE_LOG); 
                        return -1; 
                } 
                method = TLSv1_client_method(); 
                isSslInit=0; 
        } 
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);/* Create new context */ 
    if ( ctx == NULL) 
        { 
            debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Unable to create a new SSL context structure\n",TRACE_LOG); 

            //sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Unable to create a new SSL context structure: %d %s\n",errorStatus,strerror(retVal)); 
                //debug_log(debugBuf,TRACE_LOG); 

            return -1; 
    } 
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2); 
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) 
        { 
                SSL_CTX_free(ctx); 
                ctx = NULL; 
                 debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Error setting the certificate file.\n",TRACE_LOG); 
                 return -1; 
    } 

        /* Set the list of trusted CAs based on the file and/or directory provided*/ 
          if(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CertFile,NULL)<1) 
        { 
                SSL_CTX_free(ctx); 
                ctx = NULL; 
                  debug_log("SYSTEM:SSL_SOCKET:Error setting verify location.\n",TRACE_LOG); 
                  return -1; 
          } 
         SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL); 
          SSL_CTX_set_timeout (ctx, 300); 


        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */ 
        if(ssl == NULL) 
        { 
                sprintf(debugBuf,"SYSTEM:SOCKET:SSL:Unable to create SSL_new context\n"); 
                debug_log(debugBuf,DEBUG_LOG); 
                if(ctx != NULL) 
                  SSL_CTX_free(ctx); 
                return -1; 
        } 

          return 0; 
}
```

Also is it advised to maintain SSL context for new connections or should we destroy and re init the ssl context??

Added PCAP info:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60pejPe6yiSUk1MMmI1cERMaFU/view?usp=sharing

client: 198.168.51.10 (198.168.51.10), Server: 192.168.96.7 (192.168.96.7)

Answer (score 7):

> We are trying to establish ssl connection with a server. We notice that SSL_CONNECT is failing with error code "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL".

This is usually the case if the other side is simply closing the connection. Microsoft SChannel does this on many kind of handshake problems instead of sending a TLS alert back. This can happen for problems like invalid protocol or no common ciphers etc. It also can happen if you try to do a TLS handshake with a server which does not speak TLS at all on this port. Look at logs at the server side for problems.

Of course it can also be something different so you might check the errno to get more details about the problem. It might also help if you do a packet capture to check what's going on on the wire. Best would be to do this capture on the client and server side to make sure that no middlebox like a firewall is tampering with the connection.

> Also is it advised to maintain SSL context for new connections or should we destroy and re init the ssl context??

The context is just a collection of settings, certificates etc and is not affected by the SSL connection itself. You can reuse it for other connection later or at the same time.

EDIT, after the packet capture was attached:

There are multiple TCP connection in the file between client and server and only inside a single one the client tries to initiate a handshake, i.e. the ClientHello can be seen. The server closes the connection. A few things a interesting:

- TCP handshake takes very long. The server only replies after 1.6 seconds after receiving the SYN with the SYN+ACK. Also the other replies take 800ms which is very long given that both addresses are in a private network (192.168.0.0). This might indicate a slow connection or VPN (this is about the latency of a satellite link), some middlebox (firewall) slowing everything down or a really slow server.
- Client sends TLS 1.0 request. It might be that the server will do only TLS 1.1+. Some TLS stacks (see above) simply close the connection on such errors instead of sending an unsupported protocol alert. But given that the server is slow it might also be old and only support SSL 3.0 or lower.
- Client does not use SNI extension. More and more servers need this and might simply close if they don't get the extension.

It is hard to know what really is going on without having access to the server. I recommend to look for error messages on the server side and use tools like [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) to check the requirements of the server, i.e. supported TLS versions, ciphers etc.

Apart from that client offers dangerously weak ciphers like various EXPORT ciphers. This looks for me like the defaults of a considerably old OpenSSL version.

Comment: Is it advised to add " SSL_set_mode(*ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);"  ... Also due you see any other issue on my connect floe..Ami missing something...

Comment: Also i have captured some wireshark packets for this failure and notice that switch is closing the connection. since, the failure is very random & continous when occurs having trouble in fixing this. However, is there something in specific should i look in with wiresharkdata??

Comment: SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY only affects blocking transports and it looks like your are trying to do non-blocking. Also, you treat SSL_WANT_WRITE the same as SSL_WANT_READ, i.e. wait that the socket gets readable. This is of course wrong. In the packet capture you should have a look at which point in the TLS handshake it breaks, which might indicate if the server has a problem with protocol or ciphers or if there is a client certificate missing or something like this.

Comment: Yes missed adding "if (ret = WANTREAD) { 
       select(fd+1, fd, NULL, NULL, &tv); 
   } else { 
       select(fd+1, NULL, fd, NULL, &tv); 
   } " should solve the pointed issue..Also thanks for pinting the error..

Comment: Added wire data for the connection. Request your suggestions

Comment: Thanks for giving deep insights on the issue. We are trying to reach server people on this. However, there are certain doubts still presist. 1. With same server somtimes sslconnect works in same day for couple of hours looks very random.  2. we are using default 0.9.8 OPENSSL library from our end (will this be a problem) ..3. Regarding SNI : Is it must to set SNI or is it servers call

Comment: 4. " server is slow it might also be old" : Is that i am missing any fallback option available like (TLSV1 fails it should try for SSLV3) ??

Comment: @Ragav: SNI must be set on the client side, but it is usually only required if there are multiple hostnames with different certificates behind the same IP address. And if fallback to SSLv3 is possible depends on the server settings. And if it sometimes works and sometimes not it might just be a connection problem or some middlebox in between. Like I said: there is an unusual high latency which might be caused by something slow and maybe intercepting in between.

Comment: The advises that you pointed to address were excellent. But, still the isue is not yet resolved.
When we contacted theh network team about the latency they almost conclude that the issue is not from there end. They say the network is VSAT and it is slow connection.

For random connectivity they ask us to check the issue from our end. They were not able to respond with any specific reason for closing the connection.

Comment: For further debugging i was trying to execute SSLYZE tool. Seems the tool requires SSL certificate and Private key. But In our case we do not pocess any private key from our. We have only certicate. Even for SSL_CONNECT loading private key is optional. How do i handle this.

Comment: SSLYZE does not require any private key unless you are using client certificates in which case you need the private key in your application too. Maybe you should look again at the documentation of the tool.